# rethinkdb getAll: order output by args order

Tags: rethinkdb

Is there a way to order the output of a getAll query in rethinkdb by the input order of the args?

I try to do following:

```
r.db('aDatabase').table('aTable').getAll(r.args([3,2,4,1]))
```

Because I added the items in the order 1, 2, 3, 4 I also get them back in that order. But I would like to get them in the order specified in the query (3,2,4,1).

Is there a way to make rethinkdb respect the way I ordered my input arguments or do I have to order them manually afterwards?

By the way: the above ids are only an example and are in reality uuids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `r.expr([3, 2, 4, 1]).concatMap(function(id) { return TABLE.getAll(id); })`, but it will be a little slower.

Comment: Is that faster than using `map` with `get` (instead of `getAll`)?

Comment: If you use `get`, you'll end up with `nil`s in your output stream for any keys that don't exist, which you'll have to filter out afterward.